# Pass specific variables from one shell script to another?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script named test.sh with:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=hello 
sh test2.sh $var1="/var/log"
```

My test2.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function jumpto
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}


start=${1:-"start"}

jumpto $start

start:
echo "variable -- " $var1
```

This does not work due to I used **jumpto** function. When execution, always **$var1** assigned to the **$1** variable in **jumpto** function.

Is there a different way to do this.?

Comment: There is `source` for passing vars from one script to another. And `envsubst` probably.
Also there is no sense to create bash script (#!/bin/bash) but run it with `sh`.

Comment: @Ivan Problem was when pass **$var1** to **test2.sh**, due to **jumpto** function it won't work.

Comment: @sanjeewa you are passing `hello=/var/log` as the first parameter (`$1`), so `start` gets set to that, and that's what gets passed to the `jumpto` function. BTW, it looks like you are trying to kluge `goto` into bash, and that's just a bad idea on any number of levels.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the advice. I was trying to use like microservice architecture to larger bash script. Trying to find out is there any possibility to do that.

Comment: **Never craft commands by string concatenation!** Use [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) instead!

Comment: Aside from the correct response by DudiBoy, consider as alternative to pass the value as a positional parameter. Also note that `test2.sh` in your example is not executed as _bash_ script. This may bite you if you later on decided to use bash-specific constructs in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suggest to learn about environment variable and `export` command and their scope.

Try modify your `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export var1=hello 
sh test2.sh $var1="/var/log"
```

Comment: This solution works.